# How to include a QR code feature in my app?

Tags: android, qr-code

I have been trying to build an Android application in which i need to include a qr scanning feature. And After scanning that qr code it should provide an drop down menu to choose categories to proceed with. How can i achieve this? I'll be using java to build that application. Please consider helping this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library for QR scanning

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

It will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Firebase now has a [Barcode Scanner feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/read-barcodes), including QR Code, it's free and run 100% on device.